# How to use Testng Selenium Scripts in Jmeter

Tags: selenium, jmeter

I have Testng Selenium Framework for functional testing, i have a request to reuse that for JMeter performance testing. Since I am new to Jmeter please help me in solving the problem.

Comment: There is an example in Ruby here: http://elementalselenium.com/tips/68-load-testing-revisited. Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

In JMeter we create and XML based jmx file for execution.
The selenium functional test cannot be imported to JMeter

Answer (score 0):

Configure [Jmeter recording](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) proxy and run the selenium script. All traffic from the browser will get recorded in jmeter. Then, do the correlation and parameterization. For authorization, you authorization module in jmeter.

Also, check the below link for another way:-
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter/

Please note, I am assuming that you require jmeter load testing and not GUI based execution from jmeter.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To execute the selenium related scripts what you need is to configure the webdriver sampler in jmeter and its browsers, after configuration a slight modification is required in the scripts to execute using jmeter.

For reference see the below given link

https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/